# Understanding the definition of exterior derivative

Tags: differential-forms, multilinear-algebra

What shown below is a reference form *Analysis on Manifolds* by James Munkres

[image]

So I saw that some authors define the differential operetor $d$ as a function from $\bigcup_{k=0}^\infty\mathcal{L}^k\big(\mathcal T_x(\Bbb R^n)\big)$ to $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty\mathcal{L}^k\big(\mathcal T_x(\Bbb R^n)\big)$ such that
$$
d\omega\in\Omega^{k+1}(A)
$$
for any $\omega\in\Omega^k(A)$ but anyway to give **any** definition I think that it is importat to prove  that if $h$ and $k$ are two different naturals then
$$
\Omega^k(A)\cap\Omega^h(A)=\emptyset
$$
because otherwise we do not how calculate the quantity $d\omega$ if $\omega$ is a $h$-form and $k$-form. Well it is not hard to prove that if $h,k\ge 1$ and $h\neq k$ then the above identity holds. Indeed if $x$ and $y$ are two point of $\Bbb R^n$ then
$$
\mathcal{L}^k\big(\mathcal T_x(\Bbb R^n)\big)\cap\mathcal{L}^h\big(\mathcal T_y(\Bbb R^n)\big)=\emptyset
$$
when they are different and when they are not. However unfortunately I did not be able to prove that
$$
\Omega^0(A)\cap\Omega^k(A)=\emptyset
$$
for any $k>0$ so I ask to prove it. In particualr I know that if there exist a scalar function $f$ in $\Omega^0(A)\cap\Omega^k(A)$ for some $k>0$ then
$$
f(x)\in\Bbb R\cap\mathcal{L}^k\big(\mathcal T_x(\Bbb R^n)\big)
$$
for any $x\in A$ and thus the statement follows proving that
$$
\Bbb R\cap\mathcal{L}^k\big(\mathcal T_x(\Bbb R^n)\big)=\emptyset
$$
but unfortunately I did not to prove it. Anyway if we define a $0$-tensor as an element of the set $\Bbb R^{\{0\}}$ where $0$ is the null vector of $\mathcal T_x(\Bbb R^n)$ then the above identity becames
$$
\Bbb R^{\{0\}}\cap\mathcal{L}^k\big(\mathcal T_x(\Bbb R^n)\big)=\emptyset
$$
and it trivially holds because $\mathcal{L}^k\big(\mathcal T_x(\Bbb R^n)\big)\subseteq\Bbb R^{\big(\mathcal T_x(\Bbb R^n)\big)^k}$ and
$$
\Bbb R^{\{0\}}\cap \Bbb R^{\big(\mathcal T_x(\Bbb R^n)\big)^k}=\emptyset
$$
so that the above identity follows. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: I cannot understand your pedantic confusion at all. How can a scalar be a $k$-multilinear map on a vector space (or vice-versa)? You're writing zillions of symbols, but just think about what things actually mean! Give me an injection of $\Bbb R$ into $\mathcal L^k(\Bbb R^n)$. You cannot. ... And what in the world is an elementary number theory tag doing here?

Comment: @TedShifrin Well, I understand your point of view: substantially (if I really well underastand) the identity $$\Bbb R\cap\mathcal L^k\big(\mathcal T_x(\Bbb R^n)\big)=\emptyset$$ is straightforward by the definition of tensors space and intially I thought this too but when for zeal I try to justify it formally I was strangerly not able and thus I take back what I studeid a just time ago in set theory to prove it.

Comment: So I know that the set $\mathcal L^k\big(\mathcal T_x(\Bbb R^n)\big)$ is coinainted in the set $\Bbb R^{\big(\mathcal T_x(\Bbb R^n)\big)^k}$ of all function from $\big(\mathcal T_x(\Bbb R^n)\big)^k\subseteq\big(\Bbb R^{2n}\big)^k$ to $\Bbb R$ and since $\Bbb R^{\big(\mathcal T_x(\Bbb R^n)\big)^k}\subseteq\big(\mathcal T_x(\Bbb R^n)\big)^k\times\Bbb R\subseteq\big(\Bbb R^{2n}\big)^k\times\Bbb R$ I tried to prove that $\Bbb R\cap\big(\Bbb R^{2n}\big)^k\times\Bbb R=\emptyset$ but I was not able to do it, that's all.

Comment: Anyway then I thought that this is not exetial because Mukres first define the exterior derivative for zero fomr and then for positive forms so since I proved that the postive forms are dsjoint it does not matter if (obviously impossible) a zero fomr is a positive form too. Forgive my confusion.

Comment: I think it's already been commented, but you want to think of $d$ as a collection of $d_k$, one for each natural number. That's the most constructive way to do it.

Comment: Okay, so I will accept the answer of @DanielSchleper. Thanks to much for for opinion!!! See you soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In practice, we do not actually care whether $\Omega^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\Omega^h(\mathbb{R}^n)$ are literally disjoint sets or not when $k \ne h$.  Instead, in a completely formal development, we would make it explicit that we are talking about a family of maps $d^{(k)} : \Omega^k(\mathbb{R}^n) \to \Omega^{k+1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.  However, in most situations it will be clear from context which map $d^{(k)}$ we must be thinking of applying so that putting in the explicit index would be unnecessary noise.

For a somewhat more complex example of what I mean by that last sentence, we will also have a wedge product $\wedge$ which formally is actually a family of maps ${\wedge}^{(k,\ell)} : \Omega^k(\mathbb{R}^n) \times \Omega^\ell(\mathbb{R}^n) \to \Omega^{k+\ell}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.  Then one result you can state is: for $\omega \in \Omega^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\tau \in \Omega^\ell(\mathbb{R}^n)$, we have $$d(\omega \wedge \tau) = d\omega \wedge \tau + (-1)^k \omega \wedge d\tau.$$  Now, from this context, it is straightforward to go through and assign what indices would have to be filled in for a more formal system to be able to accept the statement:
$$d^{(k+\ell)}(\omega \wedge^{(k,\ell)} \tau) = (d^{(k)} \omega) \wedge^{(k+1,\ell)} \tau +^{(k+\ell+1)} [(-1)^k \cdot^{(k)} \omega] \wedge^{(k,\ell+1)} (d^{(\ell)} \tau).$$
(Note that here, I have also made it explicit that vector addition and scalar multiplication of differential forms are also formally indexed families, i.e. we will never try to add $\omega \in \Omega^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ to $\tau \in \Omega^h(\mathbb{R}^n)$ unless $k = h$.)

---

As a side note, this point of view, that we don't really care in practice whether different sets might actually overlap or not, is part of the idea behind "type theory" as a language for mathematics.  In most type theories, the question of whether elements of unrelated types are equal becomes something that it is not even meaningful to ask, in the sense that the corresponding formulas would not qualify as "well-formed formulas".  And I'm personally convinced that outside of axiomatic set theory, a vast majority of mathematics is actually done and thought about in some version of type theory rather than in ZFC.  Certainly, ZFC is useful from a theoretical point of view because of its restricted language and few axioms, and type theory is usually not too difficult to build "on top of" ZFC.  A useful analogy to a computer science situation is to think of ZFC as a form of "machine code", and think of type theory as a higher-level language which can be translated to machine code.

Comment: I inted your point of view. Anyway if it would be $$\Bbb R\cap\mathcal L^k\big(\mathcal T_x(\Bbb R^n)\big)\neq\emptyset$$ in **ZFC** it seems to me it would be **very** stranger so coud it be the opposite? What can you say about?

Comment: Hmm, I suppose technically with $\mathcal{L}^k(\mathcal{T}_x(\mathbb{R}^n))$ being a function with real numbers embedded in the domain, if that function were also a real number then the real number would have to occur somewhere within one of the ordered pairs of that function, within the domain section of the pair; and then comparing ranks would give a contradiction.  But again, that's the sort of noise that we really shouldn't have to care about in the first place.

Comment: (And even in ZFC, the question of overlap is easy to make irrelevant if you move to using the disjoint union in defining $d : \bigsqcup_k \Omega^k(\mathbb{R}^n) \to \bigsqcup_k \Omega^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ instead of using the literal union.)

Comment: So why the last identity holds? Could you say something  about?

Comment: Well, this could be a solution. Anyway your first comment have hinted what to follow.

Comment: So we observe that $$
\mathcal T_x(\Bbb R^n)\subseteq\Bbb R^{2n}\Rightarrow\big(\mathcal T_x(\Bbb R^n)\big)^k\subseteq\big(\Bbb R^{2n}\big)^k\Rightarrow\big(\mathcal T_x(\Bbb R^n)\big)^k\times\Bbb R\subseteq\big(\Bbb R^{2n}\big)^k\times\Bbb R
$$
so that $$
\mathcal L^k\big(\mathcal T_x(\Bbb R^n)\big)\subseteq\Bbb R^{\big(\mathcal T_x(\Bbb R^n)\big)^k}\subseteq(\mathcal T_x(\Bbb R^n)\big)^k\times\Bbb R\subseteq\big(\Bbb R^{2n}\big)^k\times\Bbb R
$$ and thus if we prove that $$
\Bbb R\cap\Big(\big(\Bbb R^{2n}\big)^k\times\Bbb R\Big)=\emptyset
$$ then the statement follows.

Comment: So why the last identity holds? Could you say something about?